# How to copy the value of a column into a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

**Hi!**  Do you know how I could copy the value of a cell *[Column "DATA_2]* into a new column *[Column "NEW_DATA"]*, but only if the value is "1" or "-1" and it must be copied 2 cells above the original cell? (all other cells in the new column must be "0")

[image: DataFrame]

I'm using Pandas, could you at least help me get an idea of what functions to use?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always do

```
df['new_data'] = df['DATA_2'].shift(-2).fillna(0)
```